# How can I filter through a table using a ComboBox?

Tags: combobox, sapui5

The only thing I need to know is if I can create a value for an item in the ComboBox, then I think I will be able to accomplish the task at hand. Would I do something like:

```
var oItem1 = new sap.ui.core.ListItem("lab", {
    text: 'Lab',
    value: 'Lab'
});

var oItem2 = new sap.ui.core.ListItem("boxer", {
    text: 'Boxer',
    value: 'Boxer'
});
```

Then I would use a button to filter through the table like so:

```
var oButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
    text: "find",
    styled: false,
    press: function () {
        var oFilter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("typeOfDog", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, oItem1.getValue());
        var oFilter2 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("typeOfDog", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, oItem2.getValue());
        var allFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter([oFilter1, oFilter2], false);
        oTable.getBinding("rows").filter(allFilter);
    }
}).addStyleClass("searchButton").placeAt("search");
```

This however does not work. I'm assuming it is because I cannot create a value for a ListItem. If I can, how do I do so?

EDIT: Is there a way to do something like the CheckBox, a method equivalent .getChecked()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I used a DropdownBox instead and used the following code:

```
oDropDown.attachChange(function () { oTable.getBinding("rows").filter(new sap.ui.model.Filter("payment", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oDropDown.getValue())); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use FacetFilters also .FacetFilter consist of FacetFilterList and these are columns in the table.Based on the values selected in facetfilter table will get filterd.